# How can I serve both my website and my API on the same Domain using fastapi?

Tags: javascript, api, fastapi

I am working on a project that involves users signing up and accessing a dashboard. For this I've written an API, but I don't know how to serve them both on the same domain and also use the API to change dashboard accordingly.
the api is written in python using [FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/)
and the site is currently written in vanilla JS (for prototyping).
Is this possible?
If so, how do I go about doing it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use nginx, redirect traffic to web app on the domain and use :<ports> or cname to direct it to apis

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I had seen people recommending nginx but I'm not sure how I can use the API in the website if I use nginx.

Comment: I mean I've seen many websites do this. For example: if I want to signup for a service on their website I fill in the details, it still show some details on the site while you can see the api call on the search bar. I assumed that it is the api being called. So please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You can use whatever webserver you want for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your website consists of only static pages, you can store them in a folder and tell Fastapi to serve static files from that folder.

Here's the example taken from the docs

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles

app = FastAPI()

app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")
```

https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/static-files/?h=stat

Comment: I currently have only static files. Is it possible to call the API from within the site served using fastAPI? Sorry, if this is trivial. I am a bit confused.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. All of your static files now will point at something like "/static/path/to/static/file". If you have some javascript, you can fetch data with the url "/api/path/to/whatever"

Comment: That is great! Thank you!